# Excel Extract username from cell that has string of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have spreadsheet, that contains a string of numbers (text) I need to extract the text within the parentheses and count how many meet the critera

I tried the follow code:

```
=COUNTIF(NASC!C:C,"MID(NASC!C:C,SEARCH(zv489408,NASC!C:C,22))")
```

But it is not returning a value.

here is the string that it must search from:

```
1234595250110784533 (zv489408)
```

and its on separate sheet that labelled NASC

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work in Ubuntu and these have been tested in LibreOffice, not Excel. There may be some discrepancies between the programs.*

Your core function should be `SEARCH("(zv489408)", NASC!C:C)`. (The `22` in your example starts searching from the 22nd character in the cell; this will not find the string if it occurs earlier in the cell.) That will return the starting character of the string in that cell, or an error (probably `#VALUE!`).

You could set up another column, with the formula `=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("(zv489408)", NASC!$C1)))` in each cell (the `1` will change to the row relevant to each cell, of course), and then `SUM` that column up in another cell.

---

I have managed to find an array formula that works, but I'm warning you now, it's nasty:

```
=COUNTIF(MID(NASC!C:C, SEARCH("(", NASC!C:C) + 1, SEARCH(")", NASC!C:C, SEARCH("(", NASC!C:C)) - SEARCH("(", NASC!C:C) - 1), "zv489408")
```

(Hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` to save a formula as an array formula.)

It's nasty because it goes through all of these steps, and can't save the intermediate results:

1. Find the opening bracket.
2. Find the closing bracket after the opening bracket.
3. Subtract the position of the opening bracket from the position of the closing bracket to get the length (plus one more, to exclude the closing bracket).
4. Get the text between them.

Comment: All the strings are the same and will always start on the 22nd character.  The code you gave, is just returning true and false.  I am going to keep tinkering with this using what you gave as an example.

Comment: Yes, you need to `SUM` the `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. But I did end up finding a single formula that works; it's probably a bit more generic than you need, as I didn't see your comment until I'd posted it.